# Error woocommerce plugin in functions.php line 50

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making my landing page using php functions to call product stuff from woocommerce, but its throwing this exception. I have disabled the woocommerce plugin and it the error gone away. But I need to fix with woocommerce activated.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DateTime::format() in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\estore.com\wp-includes\functions.php on line 50
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined method DateTime::format() in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\estore.com\wp-includes\functions.php on line 50

***[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki7e4.png***

```
function mysql2date( $format, $date, $translate = true ) {
if ( empty( $date ) ) {
    return false;
}

$datetime = date_create( $date, wp_timezone() );

if ( false === $datetime ) {
    return false;
}

// Returns a sum of timestamp with timezone offset. Ideally should never be used.
if ( 'G' === $format || 'U' === $format ) {
    return $datetime->getTimestamp() + $datetime->getOffset();
}

if ( $translate ) {
    return wp_date( $format, $datetime->getTimestamp() );
}

/*line 50 ->*/ return $datetime->format( $format );
```

}

it also points the error is here at my custom landing page

`<?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Comment: Please add any relevant information as text, not images. Have you tried opening that file to see the line that causes the error?

Comment: sorry, see whats on line 50, seems nothing wrong at all

Comment: What version of PHP is this running on?

Comment: version 7.1.26 is running

Comment: Do you have any other custom classes that have the same name (`DateTime`)?

Comment: No I pretty sure do not

Comment: Check my update also please, its also pointing error in looping posts line pn my custom landing page

Comment: That's because `the_post()` is internally calling `mysql2date()` - you can see it in the stack trace you posted in the image. Well, other than having a PHP version before `format` was included or two classes with the same name clashing, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I see. It' solved! I just deactivated and reactivated the woocommere plugin and the error just and only disappeared. Thank youuu!